# Remove a dictionary from list if other list contains same dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am solving a specific problem and I would like to find out what is the most pythonic way. I have two list of dictionaries, for example:

```
l1 = [{id: '1', grade: 'A'}, {id: '2', grade: 'B'}, {id: '3', grade: 'A'}]
l2 = [{id: '1', grade: 'A'}, {id: '2', grade: 'B'}, {id: '3', grade: 'Unavailable'}]
```

There are always the same ids in boths lists, only the grades differ. Now I want to write a list comprehension to remove from l1 all the dictionaries that have Unavailable grade in l2. Meaning in this case I want to remove dict with id:3.
Can someone help me out? Much thanks

Comment: How about changing those to `"id"` and `"grade"` so that you have valid lists. You could create a set of unavailable ids from l2 and then use that to filter l1.

Comment: I believe it make much more sense to use top-level dict rather than list. The syntax would be much cleaner. Id could be the hashable key and grade value.

Comment: I believe dicts should use `str` as keys.

Answer (score 2):

You could make an intermediate set of the ids you want to remove.

```
>>> l1 = [{'id': '1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'id': '2', 'grade': 'B'}, {'id': '3', 'grade': 'A'}]
>>> l2 = [{'id': '1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'id': '2', 'grade': 'B'}, {'id': '3', 'grade': 'Unavailable'}]
>>> unavailable = {g['id'] for g in l2 if g['grade'] == 'Unavailable'}
>>> l1_fixed = [g for g in l1 if g['id'] not in unavailable]
>>> l1_fixed
[{'id': '1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'id': '2', 'grade': 'B'}]
```

Comment: Ah, right this one is the best and first.

Answer (score 1):

This works assuming l1 and l2 are of the same length. Try:

```
for dicIndex in range(len(l1)):
    if 'Unavailable' in l2[dicIndex].values():
        l1.pop(dicIndex)

print(l1)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'id': '2', 'grade': 'B'}]
```

Comment: We already know the key so `l2[dicIndex]["grade"] == "Unavailable"` would make sense.

Comment: It’s a top-level list not dict. But I do agree comprehension doesn’t make too much sense here if you’re ok with mutation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `zip`,

```
In [1]: [d1 for d1,d2 in zip(l1, l2) if d2.get('grade') != 'Unavailable']
Out[1]: [{'id': '1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'id': '2', 'grade': 'B'}]
```

If the list is not ordered so we need to sort before the list comprehension,

```
l1 = sorted(l1, key=lambda x:x.get('id'))
l2 = sorted(l2, key=lambda x:x.get('id'))
output = [d1 for d1,d2 in zip(l1, l2) if d2.get('grade') != 'Unavailable']
```

Comment: There is nothing that says l1 and l2 will be iterated in order of matching ids. And this removes ids with differing grades as well as "Unavailable".

Comment: It’s not sure they’ll always be ordered though it seems to be so in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the Pythonic way to do it

**Using List Comprehension:**

```
l1 = [{"id": '1', "grade": 'A'}, {"id": '2', "grade": 'B'}, {"id": '3', "grade": 'A'}]
l2 = [{"id": '1', "grade": 'A'}, {"id": '2', "grade": 'B'}, {"id": '3', "grade": 'Unavailable'}]

#  Incase grade is always the same in l1 and l2 
#  Except it can have a value "Unavailable" in l2
l1 = [item for item in l2 if item['grade'] != 'Unavailable']

#  Otherwise if grade can be a different value in both lists for the same index
l1 = [l1[i] for i in range(len(l2)) if l2[i]["grade"] != 'Unavailable']
```

**Output:**

```
>>> [{'id': '1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'id': '2', 'grade': 'B'}] # l1_method_1
>>> [{'id': '1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'id': '2', 'grade': 'B'}] # l1_method_2
```